# How to run webdriver.io / Appium / Mocha tests sequentially

Tags: testing, automated-tests, webdriver, appium, android-testing

I am trying to run some of my tests sequentially. My test environment is:

- Javascript
- Webdriver.io
- Mocha
- Appium
  I am first just trying to get two to run. I keep getting an error that doesn't have much definition to it. Maybe someone more experience can give me some advice? I get a 404 time out error immediately in my Appium server log.

Here is my wdio.conf.js file:

```
 
 // ======================== RIGHT HERE IS WHERE YOU TELL IT WHAT TESTS TO RUN - - YOU CAN RUN MULTIPLE TESTS IN A ROW ================================== ================= ================= ================= ================= ================= =================
specs: [ 
 // ['./tests/specs/signUp_process.js'],
   // ['./tests/specs/forgotPassword.js'],
     ['./tests/specs/login_process.js', 
 './tests/specs/createACompany.js'],
 // ['./tests/specs/editProfile_companyANDpersonal.js'],
 // // THiS EDITS THE COMPANY TOO^
   // ['./tests/specs/createASiteANDEdit.js'],
   // ['./tests/specs/editSettings.js'],
   // ['./tests/specs/createAStandardJob.js'],
   // ['./tests/specs/createA4wayJob.js'],
   // ['./tests/specs/createADisposableMaterialJob.js'],
   // ['./tests/specs/createAUnknownDropOFFJob.js'],
 //  ['./tests/specs/createAUnknownPickUpJob.js'],
   // ['./tests/specs/createAMMHMAJob.js'],

 
],

 // Patterns to exclude.
 exclude: [
   // 'path/to/excluded/files'
 ],
 //
 // ============
 // Capabilities
 // ============
 // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same
 // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test
 // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in
 // order to group specific specs to a specific capability.
 //
 // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
 // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
 // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
 // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
 // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
 // from the same test should run tests.
 //
 maxInstances: 10,
 //
 // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the
 // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities:
 // https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator
 //
 capabilities: [
   {
     platformName: "android",
     "appium:deviceName": "Pixel4",
     "appium:platformVersion": "10",
     "appium:automationName": 'UIAutomator2',
     // automationName: the name of the driver you wish to use
     "appium:app": "/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/android/android-official-new/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
     "appium:appPackage": "com.truckpay.truckpay",
     // appPackage is for java for androids
     "appium:appActivity": "com.truckpay.Activity.Activity_ScreenSlide",
     //  appActivity: Where to go in the app initially
     "appium:remoteAppsCacheLimit": "0",
   },
 ],
 //
 // ===================
 // Test Configurations
 // ===================
 // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
 //
 // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
 logLevel: 'info',
 // HELPS US TRACE THE BUGS
 //
 // Set specific log levels per logger
 // loggers:
 // - webdriver, webdriverio
 // - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/devtools-service, @wdio/sauce-service
 // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework
 // - @wdio/local-runner
 // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter
 // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils
 // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
 // logLevels: {
 //     webdriver: 'info',
 //     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info'
 // },
 //
 // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use
 // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests).
 bail: 0,
 //
 // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts
 // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl.
 // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url
 // gets prepended directly.
 baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
 // DONT HAVE TO WORRY ABOUT THIS BECAUSE WE ARE RUNNING IT ON APPIUM
 //
 // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands.
 waitforTimeout: 10000,
 //
 // Default timeout in milliseconds for request
 // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response
 connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
 //
 // Default request retries count
 connectionRetryCount: 3,
 //
 // Test runner services
 // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance
 // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new
 // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process.
//   services: ['appium'],
 services: [
   ['appium', {
       args: {
           address: 'localhost',
           port: 4723
       },
       logPath: './'
   }]
],
 // THIS TELLS IT WHAT TO USE

 // Framework you want to run your specs with.
 // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber
 // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks
 //
 // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed
 // before running any tests.
 framework: 'mocha',
 // THIS TELLS IT WHAT TO USE
 //
 // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole
 // specFileRetries: 1,
 //
 // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts
 // specFileRetriesDelay: 0,
 //
 // Whether or not retried specfiles should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue
 // specFileRetriesDeferred: false,
 //
 // Test reporter for stdout.
 // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
 // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter
 reporters: ['spec'],

 //
 // Options to be passed to Mocha.
 // See the full list at http://mochajs.org/
 mochaOpts: {
   ui: 'bdd',
   timeout: 600000,
 },
 //
};
```

Here is an image of my file structure:

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgfJi.png)

Here is the error log:

```
Execution of 1 workers started at 2022-10-05T23:04:08.580Z

2022-10-05T23:04:08.591Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2022-10-05T23:04:11.272Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2022-10-05T23:04:11.272Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: 
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:11.426Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in android - /tests/specs/login_process.js, /tests/specs/createACompany.js
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:11.524Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:11.547Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:11.547Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'android',
[0-0]       'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel4',
[0-0]       'appium:platformVersion': '10',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': '/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/android/android-official-new/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
[0-0]       'appium:appPackage': 'com.truckpay.truckpay',
[0-0]       'appium:appActivity': 'com.truckpay.Activity.Activity_ScreenSlide',
[0-0]       'appium:remoteAppsCacheLimit': '0'
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'android',
[0-0]     'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel4',
[0-0]     'appium:platformVersion': '10',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': '/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/android/android-official-new/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
[0-0]     'appium:appPackage': 'com.truckpay.truckpay',
[0-0]     'appium:appActivity': 'com.truckpay.Activity.Activity_ScreenSlide',
[0-0]     'appium:remoteAppsCacheLimit': '0'
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:17.152Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:21.987Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 3/3
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:21.987Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:21.987Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'android',
[0-0]       'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel4',
[0-0]       'appium:platformVersion': '10',
[0-0]       'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
[0-0]       'appium:app': '/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/android/android-official-new/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
[0-0]       'appium:appPackage': 'com.truckpay.truckpay',
[0-0]       'appium:appActivity': 'com.truckpay.Activity.Activity_ScreenSlide',
[0-0]       'appium:remoteAppsCacheLimit': '0'
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'android',
[0-0]     'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel4',
[0-0]     'appium:platformVersion': '10',
[0-0]     'appium:automationName': 'UIAutomator2',
[0-0]     'appium:app': '/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/android/android-official-new/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk',
[0-0]     'appium:appPackage': 'com.truckpay.truckpay',
[0-0]     'appium:appActivity': 'com.truckpay.Activity.Activity_ScreenSlide',
[0-0]     'appium:remoteAppsCacheLimit': '0'
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:24.302Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:24.303Z ERROR webdriver: unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
[0-0]     at getErrorFromResponseBody (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:198:12)
[0-0]     at NodeJSRequest._request (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriver/build/request/index.js:166:60)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[0-0]     at async startWebDriverSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:68:20)
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:46:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:77:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:223:56)
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:176:25)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:88:19)
[0-0] 2022-10-05T23:04:24.303Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
[0-0] An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: socket hang up
[0-0]     at startWebDriverSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:73:15)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:46:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:77:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:223:56)
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:176:25)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (/Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:88:19)
[0-0] FAILED in android - /tests/specs/login_process.js, /tests/specs/createACompany.js
2022-10-05T23:04:24.416Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2022-10-05T23:04:24.417Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:15 

2022-10-05T23:04:24.418Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2022-10-05T23:04:24.670Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2022-10-05T23:04:24.671Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
christianfortin:appium-docs-test-hello-world/ (main✗) $
```

Answer (score 0):

To get them to run sequentially you'll need to adjust the maxInstances to a lower threshold so they run in order.

```
// First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's
// say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have
// set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec
// files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time
// and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities
// from the same test should run tests.
```